# How to align the input field to center of page that is inside the div tag in html

Tags: html

I have the login page which consists of html input field and also the submit and cancel button.And these are there inside the div tag,so how to align the input text box and also submit and cancel to the center of page

This is my html code:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
       <script>
       .ApplicationName{
       font-family: 'Times New Roman';
       font-style: normal;
       font-size:40px;
       color: rgba(66,138,201,1);
       height:38px;
       width:auto;
       font-weight: bold;
       margin-left: 380px;
       text-align:center;
       }           
       </script>

      <div class ="container" style="background-color: rgba(66,138,201,1)">
      <div class ="navbar-header">
      <p  class="ApplicationName" style="color: white;">JIRA-STATUS TRACKER</p>
      </div>
      </div>
      <br>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
           <label for="name">Search by Manager</label>
            <form action = "indextable.html" method="GET">                 
             <input type="managerid" name = "ManagerId" class="form-control" id="ManagerId"   type ="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="8"  placeholder="ManagerId"></input>
             <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 3px;" this.disabled = true;>Submit</button>
             <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 3px;" value="Reset" onClick="window.location.reload()"></input>   
         </form>      
         </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code this will help you.

```css
       .ApplicationName{
       font-family: 'Times New Roman';
       font-style: normal;
       font-size:40px;
       color: rgba(66,138,201,1);
       height:38px;
       width:auto;
       font-weight: bold;
       margin-left: 380px;
       text-align:center;
       } 
       .center-align {
         text-align: center;
       }
```

```html
  <div class ="container" style="background-color: rgba(66,138,201,1)">
    <div class ="navbar-header">
    <p  class="ApplicationName" style="color: white;">JIRA-STATUS TRACKER</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group center-align col-sm-4">
         <label for="name">Search by Manager</label>
          <form action = "indextable.html" method="GET">                 
           <input type="managerid" name = "ManagerId" class="form-control" id="ManagerId"   type ="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="8"  placeholder="ManagerId"></input>
           <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 3px;" this.disabled = true;>Submit</button>
           <input type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 3px;" value="Reset" onClick="window.location.reload()"></input>   
       </form>      
       </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply

```
text-align: center;
```

to your row class

Edit

add text-center class along side row as it looks like you're using bootstrap
also you're using `<script>` tags instead of `<style>` tags for your styling